# Stack.Pop() using LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

Just so you all know this is a homework problem and I have spent hours trying to figure this little thing out. My `pop()` won't work. This is my current code for `pop()`:

```
StackElement Stack::Pop(){

Position temp;
temp = stack.CurrentEntry();
stack.Delete();
return temp;}
```

I am using `Delete()` which is a linked list based `delete()` function that goes like this:

```
void LinkedList::Delete(){

if (current == first && AtEnd()){
    // Remove the memory allocation for the element's data
    delete &current->data;

    // Reset all values of the linked list to original (null) state
    current = NULL;
    pred = NULL;
    first = NULL;
}
else 
    // Checks if the current element is the first node in the lists
    if (current == first){
        // Make new first element to be the next element
        first = current->next;

        // Remove the memory allocation for the element's data
        delete &current->data;

        // The new current entry is the successor of the deleted node.
        current = first;
    }
    // When the element you're deleting is not the first node in list
    else{
        assert(!Empty());
        // Temporary node to prevent current from being marroned
        Node *tempNode = current->next;

        pred->next = tempNode;

        // Remove the memory allocation for the element's data
        delete &current->data;
        current = tempNode;

    }
}
```

When I compile, it throws me this error right here:

> Unhandled exception at 0x003E5F79 in Program5_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xF495EE12.

Comment: `delete &current->data` is one problem. It should be either `delete current->data` or `delete current`. Most likely `delete current`.

Comment: We don't know the types, but `delete &current->data;` looks wrong (why the ampersand?)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us CurrentEntry, but I bet it just returns a pointer instead of making a full copy. Then you delete the original leaving the pointer pointing at nothing. It crashes when you use the pointer returned from Pop.